# Resampling point cloud data using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point-cloud

I am working on point cloud data, but do not know how to re-sample the point cloud by equally spacing them vertically and horizontally. If possible in this direction can anyone via ArcGIS DEsktop highlight steps would be of great help.

The figure posted has point data arranged at close spacing on right to the spacing on left; how can you space them equally in the same length of the rectangle space?

[image]

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: @PolyGeo I have obtained scan for the wall, and the feature is inclined to my scan position, so as i am scanning farther points spacing is more. All i want is to equalize the spacing as prominent requirement. I do not have any prior code or knowledge for this. My first hand on the data and people around me also do not have much knowledge. Hence It will be great if you remove the hold and let others go through this.

Comment: If you have more details to improve the question then you should [edit] it rather than writing comments because potential answerers do not always have time to read the latter.  This will also trigger its review for re-opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this steps to solve your problem:

1. Add X,Y coordinate fields to your data (there is a [tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-xy-coordinates.htm) for this step).
2. Open attribute table and copy all the data into Microsoft Office Excel.
3. Manually edit points coordinates to reposition them into a shape of your custom rectangle.

At this step you can use excel's formulas to automate this process. Set coordinates for the first point, then set distance beetween X and Y coordinates as a constant values. Make some formulas to handle rules when to move points into new row and column. For example, if there are more than 100 point in a row or column - set X or Y coordinate to zero.

4. Use ArcGIS tool (available in `ArcGIS catalog` menu) to convert Excel's data backward into vector data.

Comment: This is great!! thanks one more help where to find formulae for excel.